# How do I disable Drive Extension in the Marketplace SDK Setup page?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps-marketplace

The Drive Extension checkbox is disabled. I've tried disabling the Drive SDK altogether, but it's still enabled.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible at the moment, but I'm following up with our engineering team.

Comment: Thanks. Please do let me know if there are any updates.

Answer (score 0):

When a Drive SDK configuration has been created on the Google Developers Console project the checkbox will be automatically checked. Unfortunately disabling the Drive SDK in your project will not remove that restriction. An issue has been raised with the engineering team, but for the time being the old workaround is to create a new project.